# Java - Selenium : <html> containing <html> problematic

Tags: java, selenium

I'm testing a web page with Java and Selenium API. The web page is done like this :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <frameset name="f1">
        <html>
            <frameset name="f2">
            </frameset>
        </html>    
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Using `internetExplorerDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@name='f1']"))` the good element is retrieved. But when I do `internetExplorerDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@name='f2']"))` it tells that element can't be found. When I look to children of f1 with `f1.findElements(By.xpath("*")).size();` I obtain a 0, no children are found.

How this could be solved ? Does the web page has to be changed and remove the sub html markup ? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Jean Ducrot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch to the frame before finding the element within the context OF the frame.

```
internetExplorerDriver.switchTo().frame("f1");
internetExplorerDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@name='f2']"))
```